# How can I add a directory to my $PATH variable so that I may run scripts in bash without typing out the entire file path?

Tags: bash, scripting, path, terminal

I want to run a bash script "hello.sh" from the command line using only the file name and extension.  I added the directory where this file exists  ("/Users/myusername/dev"), into the $PATH variable by editing the .bash_profile file. However, when I try to run the script, I get "command not found".  I am working on MacOSX.

Here is my $PATH variable, verified from the Terminal app:
“/Users/myusername/dev:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin”

If I move the script into the /usr/local/bin folder, also in my $PATH, the script can be run by typing it directly.  One thought I have is that there might be some user rights I need to set for the directory? Otherwise, did I not set the path correctly within $PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- permissions seem less likely to be a problem, but you *do* have to have both read- and execute-permission on the */Users/myusername/dev* directory (and its parent, etc.).
- `.bash_profile` is read for login-shells.  You may have overlooked either sourcing the file, e.g., `. ~/.bash_profile` or logging out/in.

To check typos, I use a script that shows my path in readable form (see [link](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:path)).